# Error while trying to uninstall Adobe Photoshop CS6

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, photoshop-cs6

I am trying to uninstall Adobe Photoshop CS6 on my laptop (Windows 7 home premium) but it comes up with an error saying: "DW039: Failed to load deployment file". I have CS6 cd and tried to install it but it says you need to uninstall previously installed version before you can continue. Can anybody please suggest how should I go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [Adobe Creative Suite Cleaner Tool](http://www.adobe.com/support/contact/cscleanertool.html), extract, right-click and *Run as Administrator*.